# Nodejs y Mongodb: Como iterar una una respuesta de find()

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, data

**¿Como hago para iterar sobre una respuesta de find sobre Mongodb en Nodejs?**

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
ConectarMongo()
    .then( function( db ){
        var colClientes = db.collection( "clientes" );
        var datos = colClientes.find({estado: "nuevo"});
        console.log(datos);

    })
    .catch(function( err ) {
        console.log( err );
    });
```

Esta consulta me imprime:

```
Datos {
  pool: null,
  server: null,
  disconnectHandler: 
   Store {
     s: { storedOps: [], storeOptions: [Object], topology: [Object] },
     length: [Getter] },
  bson: BSON {},
  ns: 'ventas.clientes',
  cmd: 
   { find: 'ventas.clientes',
     limit: 0,
     skip: 0,
     query: { estado: 'nuevo' },
     readPreference: ReadPreference { preference: 'primary', tags: undefined, options: [Object] },
     slaveOk: true },
  options: 
   { readPreference: ReadPreference { preference: 'primary', tags: undefined, options: [Object] },
     skip: 0,
     limit: 0,
     raw: undefined,
     hint: null,
     timeout: undefined,
     slaveOk: true,
     db: 
      Db {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        s: [Object],
        serverConfig: [Getter],
        bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],
        databaseName: [Getter] },
     promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
     disconnectHandler: Store { s: [Object], length: [Getter] } },
  topology: 
   Server {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { reconnect: [Function: reconnectHandler],
        reconnectFailed: [Function: reconnectFailedHandler],
        serverDescriptionChanged: [Function],
        serverHeartbeatStarted: [Function],
        serverHeartbeatSucceeded: [Function],
        serverHeartbeatFailed: [Function],
        serverOpening: [Function],
        serverClosed: [Function],
        topologyOpening: [Function],
        topologyClosed: [Function],
        topologyDescriptionChanged: [Function],
        attemptReconnect: [Function],
        monitoring: [Function],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Object],
        close: [Function],
        destroy: [Function: destroyHandler] },
     _eventsCount: 17,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     id: 2,
     s: 
      { options: [Object],
        logger: [Object],
        Cursor: [Object],
        bson: BSON {},
        pool: [Object],
        disconnectHandler: [Object],
        monitoring: true,
        inTopology: false,
        monitoringInterval: 5000,
        topologyId: -1,
        serverDescription: [Object],
        topologyDescription: [Object] },
     ismaster: 
      { ismaster: true,
        maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216,
        maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000,
        maxWriteBatchSize: 1000,
        localTime: 2017-10-04T00:01:55.088Z,
        maxWireVersion: 2,
        minWireVersion: 0,
        ok: 1 },
     lastIsMasterMS: 11,
     monitoringProcessId: 
      Timeout {
        _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 5000,
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idleStart: 44871,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null },
     initalConnect: false,
     wireProtocolHandler: WireProtocol {},
     _type: 'server',
     clientInfo: 
      { driver: [Object],
        os: [Object],
        platform: 'Node.js v6.11.3, LE, mongodb-core: 2.1.13' },
     lastUpdateTime: 0,
     lastWriteDate: 0,
     staleness: 0 },
  cursorState: 
   { cursorId: null,
     cmd: 
      { find: 'ventas.clientes',
        limit: 0,
        skip: 0,
        query: [Object],
        readPreference: [Object],
        slaveOk: true },
     documents: [],
     cursorIndex: 0,
     dead: false,
     killed: false,
     init: false,
     notified: false,
     limit: 0,
     skip: 0,
     batchSize: 1000,
     currentLimit: 0,
     transforms: undefined },
  logger: Logger { className: 'Cursor' },
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: true,
     highWaterMark: 16,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  s: 
   { numberOfRetries: 5,
     tailableRetryInterval: 500,
     currentNumberOfRetries: 5,
     state: 0,
     streamOptions: {},
     bson: BSON {},
     ns: 'ventas.clientes',
     cmd: 
      { find: 'ventas.clientes',
        limit: 0,
        skip: 0,
        query: [Object],
        readPreference: [Object],
        slaveOk: true },
     options: 
      { readPreference: [Object],
        skip: 0,
        limit: 0,
        raw: undefined,
        hint: null,
        timeout: undefined,
        slaveOk: true,
        db: [Object],
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
        disconnectHandler: [Object] },
     topology: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 17,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        id: 2,
        s: [Object],
        ismaster: [Object],
        lastIsMasterMS: 11,
        monitoringProcessId: [Object],
        initalConnect: false,
        wireProtocolHandler: WireProtocol {},
        _type: 'server',
        clientInfo: [Object],
        lastUpdateTime: 0,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        staleness: 0 },
     topologyOptions: 
      { host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        disconnectHandler: [Object],
        cursorFactory: [Object],
        reconnect: true,
        emitError: true,
        size: 5,
        socketOptions: {},
        socketTimeout: 360000,
        connectionTimeout: 30000,
        clientInfo: [Object],
        readPreference: [Object],
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
        bson: BSON {} },
     promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
     currentDoc: null },
  sortValue: undefined }
```

Pero yo necesito iterar sobre los datos devueltos. **¿Como hago?**

Answer (score 0):

Lo que esta sucediendo es que `colClientes.find({estado: "nuevo"});` te retorna un [`Cursor`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/cursors/) y no los datos en sí. Lo que puedes hacer es invocar su método [`toArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) que retorna una [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) y después iterar sobre los datos.

Quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
ConectarMongo()
    .then( function( db ){
        var colClientes = db.collection( "clientes" );
        colClientes.find({estado: "nuevo"}).toArray().then((datos) => {
            console.log(datos); // hacer lo que quieras con los datos
            // ...
        });

    })
    .catch(function( err ) {
        console.log( err );
    });
```